# Sharepoint 2013 Web Part Shading via CSS

Tags: css, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAvxF.jpg

I want to do this, however, I do not have access to the master pages or the Look and feel section of my Sharepoint site. I can, however, edit it in Sharepoint designer and manually change CSS there. What tag should I be using to create this. Right now my website just says like Announcements in black, and has a white background. I wish to change the background to blue or something. I'm using sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change the WebPart header background :

```
.ms-WPHeader td {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white, black);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, black);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white, black);
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, black);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF',endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0);
}
```

Comment: No dice. I put it in a content editor web part and nothing has happened. I don't have access to the master pages, would there be some way for them to disable all custom css and force their own css? I don't understand why this isn't working, it was simple enough in 2010